# Can a tuplet make notes longer?

Tags: tuplet

While reading about tuplets recently, I came across the notion of a
ratio for a tuplet. As shown in this picture, for example, a 3 eighth note to 2 eighth note tuplet would replace two eighth notes with three eighth notes.

[image: various triplet notations]

This got me wondering, what if the ratio was reversed? Could I replace 3 eighth notes with 2? Can a tuplet make notes longer or are they exclusively used to divide notes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is fairly common in 6/8 time, for example.

```
X: 1
T: Duplets in 6/8
M: 6/8
K: none
V:V1
V:V2
%%score (V1 | V2)
[V:V1][K:none clef=perc stafflines=1] BBB BBB | (2BB (2BB |
[V:V2][K:none clef=perc stafflines=1] BBB BBB | BBB  BBB  |
```

The upper staff's second measure is written in duplets, with the lower staff showing the rhythmic alignment. Each of the duplet eighth notes is 1.5 beats long, rather than the 1 beat given in the time signature.

Comment: They can also be notated in 6/8 as two dotted eighth notes beamed together. One advantage to this is you can see the 16th subdivision, 1,3,5 for eighths and 1,4 for the tuplets.

Comment: I've always found it strange that tuplets are notated with the number of notes they actually _have_ (which is immediately obvious anyway), and not the number of notes whose _space_ they take (which isn't obvious at all, and can be quite hard to determine)…

Comment: So this is a 2-3 polyrhythm?

Comment: @Kaz Yes, the second measure, because the upper part has 2 against the lower part's 3.

Comment: Wouldn't this be written as a quarter note duplet?